# What is the best way to communicate? WebServices or WebApi?

Tags: web-services, security, asp.net-web-api

Here is my project shown below. Simply using a mobile and sending basic info to system and return a basic values.

I finished my project and now I need to know how to connect mobile and database.

**1)**  In my project model what is the best way to communicate? Web Services or Web API?

**2)**  If I choose Web API how can I make the communication more secure?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no straight answer to whether you use Web Services or Web API, it comes down to the details of the application. You'll need to get an understanding of the [differences](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38691/difference-between-web-api-and-web-service).

However from what I can gather of your project, and as detailed in [this article](http://www.codefoster.com/webservicesforward/), if you can use Web API then use it.

As for making your communications in Web API secure, there are built in ways to authenticate individual requests. I suggest starting [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api).